# Overloading bool operator in D

Tags: operator-overloading, d

In C++ you would overload `operator bool() const`. In Python, you would override `__bool__()`.
What can I do in D to achieve the same result? I can't find any examples on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for "Boolean Operations" on this page: http://dlang.org/operatoroverloading.html

You implement a member function like:

```
bool opCast(T : bool)() {
     return bool_result;
}
```